# Connect to Wi-Fi with minimal installation of Centos

Tags: centos, networking, wifi

I've just installed CentOS 8 on my laptop using the minimal ISO.  While it was able to connect to my apartment's Wi-Fi during installation, I am unable to get any connectivity from the terminal.

`uname -a` prints

```
Linux localhost.localdomain 4.18.0-193.el8.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri May 8 10:59:10 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`lspci` prints

```
...
01:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
...
```

`rfkill` prints

```
ID TYPE      DEVICE                 SOFT      HARD
0  wlan      ideapad_wlan      unblocked unblocked
1  bluetooth ideapad_bluetooth   blocked unblocked
2  bluetooth hci0                blocked unblocked
3  wlan      phy0              unblocked unblocked
```

`ip l` prints

```
1. lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2. enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c8:5b:76:c4:da:b2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3. wlp1s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c8:3d:d4:7e:8f:ed brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

`nmcli radio all` prints

```
WIFI-HW  WIFI     WWAN-HW  WWAN
enabled  enabled  enabled  enabled
```

`nmcli device status` prints

```
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION
enp2s0  ethernet  connected  enp2s0
lo      loopback  unmanaged  --
wlp1s0  wifi      unmanaged  --
```

`ping 192.168.1.1` prints

```
connect: Network is unreachable
```

I'm connected to my router over the LAN so I'm able to install any packages as needed.

Also, `nmtui`, while it allows me to edit my Wi-Fi connection, does not allow me to activate said connection.  That is, the connection doesn't show up under "Activate a connection".

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands:

List available wireless networks:
`nmcli device wifi`

Connect, using SSID from above command:
`nmcli device wifi connect [ssid_name]  password [type password]`

Since you connected to your apartment's wifi, I suppose that all needed packages are installed (kernel module, firmware, wpa supplicant). If your apartment's wifi isn't password protected or if it uses WEP (older insecure encryption protocol) instead of WPA/WPA2, you may need to `yum install wpa_supplicant`.

Comment: Running the `nmcli` command above (with `ssid_name` and `password` filled in) produces `Error: No Wi-Fi device found.`.  I got `wpa_supplicant` installed.

Comment: That's weird, considering the `ip addr show` result you presented plus the fact that you've already made a connection to a wifi. Have you pressed, toggled any wifi switch on your laptop? Can you add `rfkill`, `ip l`, `nmcli radio all`, `nmcli device status` results?

Comment: Updated the OP.  To my recollection, I haven't touched anything.

Comment: The solution, which I found on another question, was installing NetworkManager-wifi.  I've marked this question as a duplicate of that question.